# Specify copy constructor to not be used as copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a class A. In this class it contains a pointer to another A.

```
class A
{
    A* sub = NULL;
};
```

I want to have an empty constructor that defaults this pointer to `NULL`, and another constructor that passes a pointer/reference. This second constructor would copy the parameter into a `new A()` object, and transfer sub from the parameter, to itself.
the class now:

```
class A
{
    A* sub = NULL
    A(A* source)
    {
        this->sub = new A(*source);//copy the source 'A'

        // we now have a copy of "source" and all of its children
        // but to prevent the "source" from deleting our new
        // children (destructor deletes children recursively),
        // "source"s children are disconnected from "source"
        source->sub = NULL;

        // this invalidates sub, but that is desired for my class
    }
}
```

There is no issue with this so far. Instead the issue is that I wanted to have the "source" variable be a reference. This is now an issue, because that would make the constructor have the signature of the copy constructor.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that this shouldn't be considered the copy constructor? If this is possible should it even be done?

Comment: You're looking for a *move-constructor*, which steals the owned resource from the original object.

Comment: Don't forget a *move-assignment* operator, too. And you should disable/delete the *copy-constructor* and *copy-assignment* operaror as well, otherwise you end up in a recursive loop. Your `sub` member is not safe to copy, only to move

Comment: Note that you can also delete your copy constructor if you don't want it usable - and this will be a compiler error rather than a runtime error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor). In particular, this exact behavior is achieved by using `std::unique_ptr`.